# Not able to add {} in URI provided by axis-adb

Tags: url, uri, axis, url-encoding

I have the following piece of Code that I need to execute

`URI uri = new URI("http://localhost:8080/rest/{data}");`

The URI in the above example is from axis2-adb-1.5.1.jar -  org.apache.axis2.databinding.types.URI

I tired using axis2-adb-1.6.1.jar as well. I get a MalformedURIException stating "Path Contains invalid character:{".
I can use a workaround and modify the URI to make it work

`URI uri = new URI("http://localhost:8080/rest/%7Bdata%7D");`

However, I am looking for options wherein I dont need to modify my input.
Moreover, can anyone answer me why does the axis jar have this limitation. I tried looking for explanations but could not find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found few days ago that its not a valid scenario to add curly braces in URL. That can be added only after proper encoding

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/databinding/types/URI.html
states
Parsing of a URI specification is done according to the URI syntax described in RFC 2396, and amended by RFC 2732.

Both RFC 2396 and RFC 2732 prescribes the following

Other characters are excluded because gateways and other transport
   agents are known to sometimes modify such characters, or they are
   used as delimiters.

unwise      = "{" | "}" | "|" | "\" | "^" | "[" | "]" | "`"

Data corresponding to excluded characters must be escaped in order to
   be properly represented within a URI.